# Custom allitems.aspx page?

Tags: 2010, list, form

What I'm trying to accomplish is when a user submits a "newform.aspx" it will direct to a page saying "Thanks for submitting" instead of showing the list and all items on it. I would assume there's an easy way of accomplishing this, but I have yet to find it. The best way I can see is to replace the current "allitems.aspx" page with a new one that contains the "thank you" text. Does that sound right? If so, what would be the basic PowerShell script for that? Please note I cannot use SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the source parameter in a query string to customize the redirect after form `submit`/`cancel`. Format looks like this:

> https://yourserver/sites/sitename/lists/listname/newform.aspx?source=https://yourserver/sites/sitename/pages/someotherpage.aspx

Note that you have to have users click from a link you create somewhere and not from the usual new item link on the list toolbar. That may or may not work for your situation.